# How to get embedded Redis metrics?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-cache, redisson

I have used Embedded Redis for caching in my springboot application. The redis runs on localhost and default `port "6379"` on application start up.

Is there a way to get metrics(memory-used, keyspace_hits, keyspace_misses, etc..) for embedded redis, from outside the application, may be command line or any `API`?

PS: I have used Redisson as client to perform cache operations with redis.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis has provided a command line interface : `redis-cli` to interact with it and get the metrics. redis-cli can be used on embedded redis as well.

1. install command line interface
   npm install -g redis-cli
2. connect to redis running locally(cmd: rdcli -h host -p port -a password )
   rdcli -h localhost
3. use any redis commands
   localhost:6379> info memory
   #Memory
   used_memory:4384744
   used_memory_human:4.18M
   used_memory_rss:4351856
   used_memory_peak:4385608
   used_memory_peak_human:4.18M
   used_memory_lua:35840
   mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.99
   mem_allocator:dlmalloc-2.8

Ref: **"Installing and running Node.js redis-cli"** section of this post https://redislabs.com/blog/get-redis-cli-without-installing-redis-server